# jquery funcao $.post or $.get

Tags: jquery

Ao invés de usar o ajax para retorno , estou vendo a função do jQuery `$.post` ou `$.get`.

Mas só consigo retornar com um echo uma coluna da tabela do mysql. ex.

```
echo $conteudo['id'];
```

Com ajax jogando o retorno vindo do select (que pode conter várias linhas) jogo tudo do array e so pego na resposta.. `echo json_encode($array);`

Como posso retornar um array que pode conter várias linhas e pegar na funcao `$.post` ou `$.get` ?

ex.

```
$("#idInp").keyup(function(){
    var idd = $("#idInp").val();
    $.post('verifica.php',{id:idd},function(resposta){
        $("#tex").empty();
        if(resposta.trim() == $("#idInp").val() ){
            $("#tex").append("nomes iguais");
        }else{
            $("#tex").append("nomes diferentes");
        }
    });     
});
$seg = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE name = :id");
$seg->bindValue(":id",$_POST['id']);
$seg->execute();

$v = $seg->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $v['name'];
```

se eu retornar apenas uma linha (echo $name['name']) irá funcionar , mais e se eu tiver 100 linhas ? Como posso fazer igual o ajax .. montar um laço e ir percorrendo a `resposta[cont].name` .. `resposta[cont].idade` .. enfim..

Answer (score 1):

Okay, pelo que entendi você deseja realizar um SELECT no banco, colocar seus registros em um array, e então, mandar para a resposta de um request ajax.

> Como posso retornar um array que pode conter várias linhas e pegar na funcao $.post ou $.get ?

Ao invés de utilizar `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`, use `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` que irá retornar um array associativo bidimensional, com cada row e suas respectivas colunas.

Para fazer um laço na resposta que o servidor vai enviar você pode utilizar a função `$.each` do jquery.

Exemplo:

```
$("#idInp").on('keyup', function(){
    var idd = $(this).val();
    $.getJSON('verifica.php',{id:idd},function(resposta){
        $("#tex").empty();
        $.each(resposta, function (indice, item) {
            if(item.nome == $("#idInp").val() ){
                $("#tex").append("nomes iguais");
            }else{
                $("#tex").append("nomes diferentes");
            }
        });
    });     
});
```

```
$seg = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE name = :id");
$seg->bindValue(":id",$_GET['id']);
$seg->execute();

$v = $seg->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($v);
```

Observações:

1. Recomendo pesquisar um pouco sobre verbos HTTP, pois no seu exemplo seria mais adequado se utilizar a função `$.get` do jquery, por representar o verbo HTTP GET. E mais especificamente, como você deseja tratar com um JSON, utilizar a função `$.getJSON` que o jquery oferece.
2. O `$(this)` no exemplo equivale a `$("#idInp")` pois está dentro do contexto desse elemento.

Bom, espero ter ajudado. :)